# Code coverage (dotCover) from 2 windows services running in parallel

Tags: dotcover

I am using a standalone dotCover installation with symbol server support to gather code coverage from manual tests.

I need to gather code coverage from **two independent windows services** (sharing the same code base) and merge the results.

How can I do that? (Any pointer into documentation would be useful).

Thanks in advance, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about how to merge snapshots, then here is the answer. You can either use the 'merge' command (console runner) or the 'Merge Coverage Snapshots' option (dotCover standalone, dotCover integrated in Visual Studio). The corresponding link as requested :) https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/help/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html#merge